# Using .formula to sum values in dynamic ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro that changes the layout of a raw excel file and displays some usefull information to the user. But I am stuck now.

I want to display the sum of some cells in a column, but the cell where the sum is and the column itself is set dynamically.

My layout looks like this:

```
        Year1         Year2         Year3 
Sum1     100            
Sum2     50             48     
Sum3                    72            81   
Sum4                                  26
------------------------------------------
Total
```

I want to display the sum of (sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4) in the Total row under each Year.
The thing is my years are set dynamically depending on the value of a parameter (i.e. I can have 2, 3 or 5 years).

I know I can do it using `Range.WorksheetFunction.Sum` but the problem is my values are subject to some changes after the macro has been used and if I use this function the values won't change afterward.

That's why I want to use the function Range.Formula to display these values as I can enter the sum like I did for the values already in the sheet.

But unlike these values (that are the sum of values in an unique column easy to select), I am not able to select the colum dynamically.

Here is what I tried to give you an idea of what I want to do if it is unclear to you:

```
For i=0 to Duration-1
Sheet2.Range("D" & RNumber + 7 + Duration).Offset(0,1+2*i).Formula="=SUM(Sheet2!" & Range("D" & RNumber + 6).Offset(0,1+2*i) & ":Sheet2!" & Range("D" & RNumber + 6 + Duration).Offset(0,1+2*i) & ")"
Next i
```

But it doesn't work as the sum doesn't recognize the range. I know I should have something like

```
"=SUM(Sheet2!E" & Firstrow & ":Sheet2!E" & Lastrow & ")"
```

but then i won't be able to select my colum dynamically.

Comment: If you put all this into a Table (or a `ListObject` in VBA) it might be easier to program.

Comment: Yes but If the data is modified, will it change the value of the sum ? (The user has to do some manual modification on the data sometimes)

Comment: Tables have built-in Total rows, which are turned off by default. They can actually contain averages, counts, etc., as well as totals. They are dynamic in that they do the operation on whatever is in that column. I don't know for sure if they fit your situation, but definitely worth exploring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem stems from the fact that you can't do things like `"Sheet2!" & D+3+1` for columns the same way you can do `"Sheet2!D" & 5+6+2` for rows. My opinion is that this is one of the many flaws created by the insane A1 reference style, and the best way to attack this problem at the root is to simply switch to R1C1 at the beginning of the macro.

```
With Application
    If .ReferenceStyle = xlA1 Then
        .ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    End If
End With
```

Some day, I plan to start a non-profit effort to rid the world of the mis-begotten `$A4:B$3` craziness altogether. But too many people are used to A1. And if you send your boss or co-worker a spreadsheet with numbers for columns, she might get upset or confused.

So the other solution is to introduce some `ADDRESS()` elements into your SUMs. The ADDRESS function takes only numbers (well, string for sheet reference) and will return a cell reference in whichever style you want.

```
For i=0 to Duration-1
    Sheet2.Cells(RNumber+7+Duration, 5+2*i).Formula = _
    "=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & RNumber + 6 & "," & 5+(2*i) & ",1,TRUE,""Sheet2""),1):" _
    & "INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & RNumber + 6 + Duration & "," 5+(2*i) & _ 
    ",1,TRUE,""Sheet2""),1))"
Next i
```

Or you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Address()` and avoid having the `INDIRECT()`s cluttering up your fomulas.